# Bulk Insert operation with multiple text qualifiers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am new to Bulk Insert script. I am trying to load the csv file below. All fields are surrounded by double quotes, If the date field have any date value then it begins with = symbol otherwise it would be an empty string. Sample csv file data below.

csv file data:

```
"Name","Market","Year","Family","Date"
"Test1                          ","C","2021","DS",="2020-12-31 00:00:00.000000"
"Test1                          ","C","2020","DS",="2020-12-31 00:00:00.000000"
"Test1                          ","C","2021","DS",""
"Test1                          ","C","2020","DS",""
"Test1                          ","C","2020","DS",="2020-12-31 00:00:00.000000"
```

I used the following code.

```
BULK INSERT #temp1 FROM 'samplerec.csv'
    WITH (
        FIRSTROW = 2
        ,FORMATFILE = 'FormatFile.xml'
        )
```

format file content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
 <RECORD>  
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>  
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>  
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>  
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=",=" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>  
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>  
 </RECORD>  
 <ROW>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Market" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Year" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Family" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Date" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>  
</BCPFORMAT>
```

When I run the bulk insert statement I am getting the error below.

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 4
```

I am sure that the date column which has no value (empty string at row3) causing the issue. I am not sure how to handle multiple field terminators in bulk insert with format file. Please assist me on this. I have to load plenty of csv files in this format.

Comment: I'm willing to bet the issue is the terminator you specified as ",=". For the third row, that symbol is missing, and thus an error is thrown.

Comment: this file is generated from other system. I have given some sample data. I am not sure how to handle that scenario in format file.

Comment: Can you ask whoever is responsible for the source system to adjust the XML file?

Comment: Your so-called CSV file isn't a valid CSV file. Consult [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).